# Нечетные числа из массива

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как вернуть нечетные числа из массива?

И еще, как возвращать отрицательные значения, а также, если это ***0***, возвращать пустой массив.
Пример:

```
input: ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7]) === [1, 3, 5, 7, 7];

input: ([0, 2, 4]) === [];

input: ([-10, 10, -11, 11, -12, 12]) === [-11, 11];

input: [] === [];
```

Написал:

```
function getNumbers(numbers) {

  let x = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {

    x = numbers[i];

    if (x % 2 == 1) {

      return [x];
    }
  }
}
```

Не понимаю где ошибся

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Не понимаю где ошибся

Везде.

```js
function getNumbers(numbers) {
  let x = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    let n = numbers[i];
    if (n % 2)
      x.push(n);
  }
  return x;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getNumbers([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getNumbers([0, 2, 4])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getNumbers([-10, 10, -11, 11, -12, 12])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getNumbers([])));
```

Comment: У меня не проходит проверку, если попробовать: 

input: [-1, 0, 1] == [], а должно == [-1,1];

input: [-10, 10, -11, 11, -12, 12] === [-11,11];

Comment: @T.V. Прочитайте первые две строчки Вашего вопроса. Мой код делает именно то, что там написано.

Comment: Да, но я же в примере написал " input: ([-10, 10, -11, 11, -12, 12]) а вернуть должен === [-11,11];"

Comment: @T.V. "+ К этому возвращать отрицательные значения" - это что? Приведите текст вопроса в соответствие с примерами ввода-вывода.

Comment: привел текст в соответствие с примерами ввода-вывода

Comment: @T.V. Почему  [-1, 0, 1] должен возвращать [-1,1]? Там же ноль.

Comment: по тому что "-1, и 1" это нечетное число.

Comment: @T.V. "если это 0, возвращать пустой массив." - это что значит?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110587/discussion-between-t-v-and-igor).

Answer (score 3):

```js
const filter = arr => arr.filter(item => item % 2 !== 0)

console.log(filter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7]))
console.log(filter([-10, 10, -11, 11, -12, 12]))
console.log(filter([0, 2, 4]))
console.log(filter([]))
console.log(filter([-1, 0, 1]))
```

Ещё можно так)